# What is the probability that the bacteria population eventually dies out?

Tags: probability

A jar begins with one bacteria. Every minute, every bacteria turns into 0,
1, 2, or 3 bacteria with a probability of 25% for each case (dies, does
nothing, splits into 2, or splits into 3). What is the probability that the
bacteria population eventually dies out?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Just to have a comparison with a later answer, a quick computational simulation gave me $p\approx 0.5865$ for staying alive.

Comment: It might be useful (??) to observe that the rate of growth is expected to be $1.5$: in fact, the expected contribution to the population of each bacterium every minute is
$$
  -1\cdot\frac 14
+
  0\cdot\frac 14
+
  1\cdot\frac 14
+
  2\cdot\frac 14
=
  + 0.5
$$
Conditioning on the fact that the population has not extinguished up to time $n$, the expected number $b_n$ of bacteria at time $n$ (starting from time $0$) is
$$
  \mathbb{E}\big(~b_n \,\big|\, b_1,\,\ldots\,,b_{n-1}\neq 0~\big) ~=~ (1.5)^n
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the probability of the bacteria dying out(it also means tht none of its offspring remains alive),

So the probability of this bacteria dying out = either itself dies out or the bacterias generated by it also dies out

So we have,$p=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}p+\frac{1}{4}p^2+\frac{1}{4}p^3$

(Reason: Cases may be either the bacteria itself dies out then there is no question of its offspring, or it remains as it is(with the probaility ($1/4$ ) and then it itself dies out (along with its next generation with the probability $p$ ,or it turns into 2 (with the probaility ($1/4$ )and then both of these diesout with its next generation with prob. $p^2$ and similarly for the case when it turns into 3 bacteria.)

$\Rightarrow p^3+p^2-3p+1=0$

$\Rightarrow (p-1)(p^2+2p-1)=0$

$\Rightarrow (p^2+2p-1)=0$(As $p\ne1$ otherwise 'everything falls apart'.Truly, I cant see why it cant be 1, just my mind says so)

$\Rightarrow p=-1+\sqrt{2}$or $p=-1-\sqrt{2}$

As p cant be -ve so the answer is $p=\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me why it couldn't be the case that $p=1$. How are you ruling that out?

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu you mean smaller than 1?

Comment: Very sorry it will be smaller than 1

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I'd have a **non rigorous**, rather intuitive, answer to the fact that the probability is not $1$. If $b_n$ denotes the population at time $n$, then the probability that eventually it dies is
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(b_n=0\,|\,b_{n-1}\neq 0)
$$
Now, if we know $b_{n-1}$, then
$$
  \mathbb P(b_n=0\,|\,b_{n-1}\neq 0) = \frac{1}{4^{b_{n-1}}}
$$
If we replace $b_{n-1}$ by its expected value $(1.5)^n$, then the probability to extinguish is **approx.**
$$
 ~\approx~ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{(1.5)^n}} ~\approx~ 0.42941
$$
Then one should discuss what we mean by $\approx$...

Comment: *Truly, I cant see why it cant be 1*... Let $q_n$ denote the probability that the $n$th generation is empty, then $q_0=0$, $q_{n+1}=f(q_n)$ for the function $f$ one knows, and the probability of extinction is $q=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}q_n$. Obviously $q$ is a fixed point of $f$, that is, $q=f(q)$. For every fixed point $x\geqslant0$ of $f$, $q_0\leqslant x$ and $f$ is increasing hence $q_n\leqslant x$ for every $n$ hence $q\leqslant x$. Thus $q$ must be the **smallest nonnegative** fixed point.